# Syncing a file from a client to a server

Tags: client, synchronization

I'm trying to keep a file updated real time with the server. Its more like a real time syncing which has a very small delay. Is there any application that lets me do this? Or would you suggest me using a local host as a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you are connected to your server - but i assume this will be something like SCP / SFTP / FTP and i dont know your OS. [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) will do excatly this what you need, you can set it to watch your Filesystem (to a specified folder) and it will update the server files as soon as your file on your drive changes.

It also supports command line features so that you can use it within your own applications.